# Yii2 Unable to verify your data submission in incognito mode

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have separated backend and frontend by using below:

Backend Config/main.php

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'sdsdsdsd-e8Fhoa1PdHzzfB2VTON9Nfh',
            'class' => 'common\components\Request',
            'web'=> '/backend/web',
            'adminUrl' => '/cpanel'
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\AdminUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-project-backend', /*'httpOnly' => true*/],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'project-backend',
            'timeout' => 60*60*24*30,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Frontend Config/main.php

```
$config =  [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'wmWhVSIv-e8Fhoa1PdHzzfB2VTON9Nfh',            
            'class' => 'common\components\Request',
            'web' => '/frontend/web'
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-project-frontend', /*'httpOnly' => true*/],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
            'name' => 'project-frontend',
            'timeout' => 60*60*24*30,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],        
    ],
    'params' => $params,
    //'defaultRoute' => 'site/index'
];
```

Now it is working perfectly in normal browser mode. But when ever i am trying to login using incognito mode, on first attempt it gives below error:

> Unable to verify your data submission

After that, if i reload the page and try to login again, it works normally.

My form is generated using ActiveForm, so CSRF token is available in login page.

So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yo can specify the validation false in specific controller / actions

include the Yii class

```
use Yii;
```

inside the action

```
Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

or inside the controller

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Comment: But that decrease the security. I don't want to disable csrf token.

Comment: if you have using activeform

Comment: insert a csrf token hidden input like <input type="hidden" name="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?>" value="<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>" />

Comment: But that CSRF token is already there because i have used ActiveForm.

Comment: if u using ajax submition or normal post

Comment: Add this in the head section of your layout: <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>

Comment: Normal Post Request.

Comment: Check whether there is hidden input in your form with CSRF token

Comment: Yes, there is meta tag as well as hidden _csrf-backend field.<input type="hidden" name="_csrf-backend" value="NmVNLlQ5T3BFEwVYFXccOVkyNFwRYB0yfzUSQWJcAURcPX1PH0B8IQ==">
<meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf-backend"><meta name="csrf-token" content="NmVNLlQ5T3BFEwVYFXccOVkyNFwRYB0yfzUSQWJcAURcPX1PH0B8IQ==">

Answer (score -2):

You need to set validation false

Set this code inside the action

```
 Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

Set complete controller validation false

```
$this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
```

This will work